# Filter store on server side in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, filter, extjs4, store, extjs4.1

I have to filter a grid store from a set of textfield/combobox inserted in the top of the page in a separated Ext.form.Panel.
I use this code for do the grid filter:

```
doGridFilters : function() {
        //storeClients.clearFilter();
        var client_Id = Ext.getCmp('Id_form').getValue();
        var filter1 = Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter',{
             root:'list',
             comparison: 'eq',
             property: "Id",
             value: client_Id
        });

        storeClients.getProxy().extraParams = { filter: filter1 };
        storeClients.load();
    },
```

but the store don't perform any type of filter.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the server side receiving for parameters?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using Ext.util.filter here? I see that you only need the 'client_Id' property.. pass it as
storeClients.getProxy().extraParams.filter = client_Id; and handle the 'filter' on your server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remotefiltering is quite easy:

- The store must be configured with [remoteFilter](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-property-remoteFilter) so that the proxy
  will handle and pass all applied filter
- Next apply a filter with
  [store.filter('propertyName', 'filtervalue')](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter). The store will now
  automaticly loading after a filter get applied.
- Expect a a list of
  filters at the serverside which looks like
  `...filter:[{property:'Name', value:'value'}]...`

And that's all. The `remoteFilter` property can be changed each time before applying a filter. For your case:

```
doGridFilters : function(grid) {
    var store = grid.store;
    store.clearFilter();
    store.remoteFilter = true;// optional
    var client_Id = Ext.getCmp('Id_form').getValue();
    store.on('load', function(s){ s.remoteFilter = false; }, this, { single: true }) // optional
    store.filter("Id",client_Id);
}
```

Note:
The proxy will always only apply the property-value paired filter, nothing more [ExtJS 4.1.1] For more you will need to override the responsible proxy function

Comment: hyperlinks are broken.